# NSDateComponents don't change hour component correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

i can't understand why i can't change the hour of a NSDate correctly, using NSDateComponents, i'll do it in this way:

```
NSDateComponent components = [calendar components:  (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

[components setMinute:myMinute];
[components setHour:7];

NSDate *myNewDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@",myNewDate);
```

but the NSLog is this:

```
2012-12-08 06:00:00 +0000
```

there is one hour of difference, i have set 7 but is 6 anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its the timezone - the NSDate is printed with GMT time as it has no notion of timezones

use

```
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```

to make the components GMT and reflect your time set

---

working example

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:  (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];

    [components setMinute:50];
    [components setHour:7];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSDate *myNewDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    NSLog(@"%@",myNewDate);
}
}
```

Comment: what time zone i have to use?

Comment: Yep, it's always the timezone.